# Python if statement not executing

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
#   TEST
import sys  
a=sys.stdin.readline()    # here the user inputs the string "HELLO"  
print a
if a == "HELLO":  
    sys.stdout.write("GOOD_BYE")  
print "AAAAAAAAAAA"  
raw_input('\npress any key to continue')
```

Hi there. I am new to Python.
I am using Python 2.7.11.
I do not understand why control is not entering the `if` statement.
The output for the given code comes out as

```
HELLO  
HELLO   
AAAAAAAAAAA
press any key to continue
```

**NOTE**: The first "HELLO" above is user input
I've tried `sys.stdout.flush()` for the `sys.stdout.write()` statement. But it doesn't seem to help.
If I write the same code with `a=raw_input()` instead of the second line, it works perfectly fine.
Can anyone explain the reason for this.

Answer (score 2):

`readline` comes with a newline character at the end. So what you are actually doing is comparing

```
HELLO\n == HELLO
```

which is actually false.

Do `a.rstrip()` to remove newline.

Answer (score 0):

readline() function read newline character from standard input console. Please use rstrip("\n") to remove the same.

```
import sys  
a=sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
print (a)
if a == "HELLO":  
    sys.stdout.write("GOOD_BYE")  
print ("AAAAAAAAAAA")
raw_input('\npress any key to continue')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'in' instead of '==' in your if condition, sometimes the lines might have some hidden characters.

```
if "HELLO" in a:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pressing 'ENTER' after input string to send input. So your input is 'HELLO\n' while your if statement 'if' condition is 'a == "HELLO"'.

Use strip() method. The method strip() returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning and the end of the string (default whitespace characters).

So new working code :

```
import sys  
a=sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
a=a.strip() # This will remove \n from input
print (a)
if a == "HELLO":  
    sys.stdout.write("GOOD_BYE")  
print ("AAAAAAAAAAA")
raw_input('\npress any key to continue')
```